# How to move the taskbar postition in Windows XP using regedit?

Tags: taskbar

How do I move the taskbar postition in Windows XP by using `regedit`?

For example, move it from the bottom to the top of the desktop, not using the mouse.

Comment: The key is here: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects2 "settings", but good luck decyphering it. Also, without you to physically move it, there is no way I know of to make that happen except logging out and back in.

Answer (score 2):

Check out method 3 [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1066-taskbar-move-location-desktop-screen.html?ltr=T). Someone has made four registry files to change to each of the taskbar positions (top, bottom, left and right).